# Laptop froze, turned it off, now boots extremely slow

Tags: boot, laptop, windows-10, battery

My laptop froze while browsing the web, I couldn't open anything not even taskmanager.

I turned it off by holding the power button.

Ever since then, it's booting extremely slow (5-8 min or so). Also the battery doesn't seem to charge anymore. Besides booting slow, it runs perfectly normal and smooth but sometimes becomes unresponsive again after 20 min and forces me to hardreboot it again.

What are some things I need to check to make sure what the problem is?

The freeze might have been due to overheating...

Comment: If laptops overheat they usually shutdown (without any notice) rather than freeze...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to the CMD as an administrator and running a check disk on the os drive. Here is a link for the command.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd637756.aspx